# Delphi: Missing Dcu

Tags: delphi

> [DCC Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(7): F1026 File not found: 'MyBitBtn.dcu'

Unit1 is a VCL Form for test purposes.

I have installed a design time package which contains a custom component that derived from TBitBtn. I can load the MyBitBtn in the Delphi IDE, load up the custom images I coded in design time and it seems like it works fine, at least visually. I get the above compile time error when I try to compile the test project.

I have a package group that has one design time package and one run time package. Design time package registers the component and Runtime package inherits the TBitBtn and has the custom code in it. **The design time package contains the RunTime DCP file in the requires section**.

The moment I insert the custom button on the test form, IDE creates the USES clause for MyBitBtn file. And that file apparently can't be found. Shouldn't that be part of the package installed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most probable you did not set 'Unit output directory' option in your runtime package, so package .dcu's are not available; I usually set it to `$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp` and have no problems.

Generally, the .dcu's of a runtime package should be available via global IDE library path if you want your package to be available to any project:

[image: lib path].

You should either use one of the existing paths or add your own.

Comment: This is one of the most mystery issue when installing a package that **requires** another package! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

The design part works, but for run time, the compiler must be able to find the dcu. 
You can do that either...

1. By adding the dcu folder to the library path of the IDE.
2. By adding the dcu folder to the search path of the project.
3. Or by adding the dcu explicitly to the project.

I would choose the first option. Since it's an installed component, you would want it to be available for any project, so setting the library path makes the most sense.

Answer (score 2):

define the path where this dcu is stored in system environment. And dont forget to include it in Delphi env paths.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ZEOS files, open packages, choose your version(DelphiXE10/Delphi7 ...) then go to the Win 32 file, open it and open Debug folder. Copy every thing, go to Program Files, Embarcadero, Studio, 17.0, lib, Win 32, Debug and paste, do the same in every win32 folder... Hope it helps :)