# Using a custom component

Tags: delphi, components, custom-component, delphi-xe3, world-of-warcraft

I'm making an application that has to do with World of Warcraft.
To keep it short; You can pick talents that give you certain skills, in my application I added a talent calculator. Here you can pick talents, each talent has a description.
This is shown, like all spells and items, in a tooltip. For an example check [here](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/tool/talent-calculator#d!) and hover over one of the talents.

So I want to make these tooltips too.
To do this I created a custom component following 2 guides

[Guide 1 here](http://www.delphidabbler.com/tips/74)

[Guide 2 here](http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc080701a.htm)

Now I made my component based on a panel. Made a package and installed it which all works.
It also shows in the list of components at design time.
Then I drag it onto my form, it gets automaticly included in the uses however...
When I try to run/build/compile my application I get an error and it says:
`Cannot resolve unit name 'Tooltip'`
and I have no idea how to fix this.

There are plenty tutorials that show you how to make a custom component but none of them talks about this problem. Am I doing something wrong?

Any advice will be very welcome :)

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976616/delphi-missing-dcu/13976814

Comment: I looked at the accepted answer on that question and checked it but my settings are like that already im affraid

Comment: is your exe built monolithic or with runtime packages ? did you tried include path to `Tooltip.pas` file in you'r application's options `search path` ?

Comment: Are we to assume that "Tooltip" is the name of the unit where your component is defined?

Comment: @RobKennedy Yes, it is. Maybe I should have mentioned that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to setup the common `library path` and `search path`.

Open from IDE-Menu `Tools\Options`

Walk to `Environment Options\Delphi Options\Library`

1. Edit `Library Path` and add the Path containing the component compiled libraries (`.dcu` files) **or** the path containing the component source files
2. Edit `Search Path` and add the Path containing the component source files (this is optional but helpful when debugging)

You have to repeat theses steps for all platforms your component will be used. But if you put the `library path` to compiled libraries, you have to ensure the right `.dcu` for the platforms.

Comment: This was it indeed, I found out later yesterday :) Thanks