# TImage Uses dxGDIPlusClasses.dcu

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I've used the trial of DevExpress but it's expired. Now when I add a standard TImage and try to compile it gives me the error:

[dcc32 Fatal Error] filter.pas(9): F1026 File not found: 'dxGDIPlusClasses.dcu'

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I believe you do not add a standard TImage component. Or your question is just a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976616/delphi-missing-dcu

Comment: `filter.pas` is not part of the standard Delphi VCL/RTL, and adding a standard `TImage` won't refer to it, so you're not using a standard `TImage` or the problem is elsewhere (like something in your `uses` clause that pulls in the DevExpress code. If the trial of DevExpress has expired, remove it. It should have an uninstaller, but if it doesn't just manually remove it. (I can't tell you how, because you didn't tell us what Delphi version you're using.) Then remove all of the DevExpress related units from your source code.